# Upgradation from Flex Builder 3 standard to Flex Builder3 Professional

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flexbuilder

I had purshased one licenses for each, flex builder 3 standard as well as flex builder professional. First, I installed flex builder 3 standard and entered the license key, it worked. As it was standard charting library has 'flex trial' water mark. Then I tried to uninstall flex builder 3 standard and install flex builder 3 professional again on 'same machine'. But here I faced the real problem, as soon as I run the exe, the license key automatically gets copied from windows registry file and it behaves as standard edition. Then I tried to use 'manage flex license' option and use 'upgrade to professional' option. Now as my key is for 'Flex 3 professional' and not 'upgrade to Flex 3 professional'  it does not accept as valid key. I have few softwares which restrict me from reformatting my system

What should I do now?
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks JStriedl. 
As you rightly said, the adobe only has the solution to this problem. I got an opportunity to talk to Matt Chotin and he has sorted this out.

There's a 'license.properties' file that contains this license info. Generally its in  'C:PreogramFiles/Adobe/Flex'. You simply need to delete this file. On restarting Flex Builder you can give the desired license file and lo, that workds :)

Please let me know, if any one still face any issue in this regard. I will try to help.

Comment: In Windows 7, I found the license.properties files with the license key in C:/ProgramData/Adobe/Flex

Comment: I'd just rename the original file (in case there's an issue with the new license)

Answer (score 1):

that sounds like something you might want to hit up Adobe support for perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP, the path for license.properties is like:
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Adobe\Flex
If it is different for you, try your Windows Login ID instead of "All Users" in above path.